# Android - Emulator showing garbled layout

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing an android app. So far I've been testing everything on my Galaxy Nexus with android 4+. I've done all my programming with backwards compatibility in mind.

I'm very close to release, and want to make sure that it runs okay on API 9+. Since I don't have a real android 2.3 phone, I'm using the emulator.

Everything seems to work fine, but the layout is sometimes okay, and sometimes completely garbled!

[image]

The background is horrible, and `TextView`s are a lot of times missing. But sometimes they're okay for just a few moments before garbling up.
How reliable is this emulator? Is this how it would really look if I ran it on a real machine? What can cause this?

EDIT: 
The layout in the screenshot is made up of 7 small `ViewGroups` containing `ListViews`.
This is the code for the main background drawable (the blue-green-gray garbled one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/main_bgtile"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

EDIT2:
I also noticed that when a transaction animation when switching fragments is played, the fragments look perfect for the duration of the animation, and then re-garble when it's done.

**EDIT 3:
My logcat seems to be flooded with the following error:**
`10-09 00:41:40.385: D/skia(327): SkGL unimplemented: stroke path`

A few dozens of those. What should I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean android 2.3.2? That would be API level 9?

Comment: Regarding layouts, I've never notice any difference between emulator and real device, with the exception form the ones resulting from different screen density and size.

Comment: @Greg: Correct; I've meant API 9 and my brain added an extra "2" to the version :).

@Luis: Hmm, that's troubling. If I can't find the root of this problem soon I will have to raise the `minSdkVersion` until I do

Comment: Yeah the emulator is pretty good about actually emulating the version. I mean it's basically just mocking out hardware. That being said, if you don't mind me asking, what is the layout for this doing? I mean these seem like normal widgets inside of a gridView or tablelayout? There aren't any opengl or surfaceviews in it are there? That will be weird on the emulator because without gpu emulation (non existent until higher API levels) you get weird results.

Comment: Nope, just regular `LinearLayouts` and `ListViews`. I've edited in the code for the background drawable that got mangled; maybe it would help us figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it:

I'm using actionbarsherlock; and for some reason I decided to disable the actionbar in the style, but then re-request it in the activity.

By removing this line from my onCreate() method in my activity, I was able to solve the problem:
`this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)`